# In Python, how to define a function which inserts the arguments of the function to a table in database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-insert

i want to define a function (named "kayitEkle") which inserts the arguments of function to a table (named "biTablo") in database:

```
import sqlite3

connect = sqlite3.connect("obs.db")
cursor = connect.cursor()

def tabloOlustur():
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS biTablo(ad TEXT, soyad TEXT, numara TEXT, puan REAL)")
    connect.commit()


tabloOlustur()

def kayitEkle(ad, soyad, numara, puan):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO biTablo(ad, soyad, numara, puan) VALUES(? ? ? ?)",(ad,soyad,numara,puan))
    connect.commit()

kayitEkle('ahmet', 'yılmaz', '08067', 50)
```

but i get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/ikinciBahar/ogrenmeDatabase.py", line 234, in <module>
   kayitEkle('ahmet', 'yılmaz', '08067', 50)
 File "C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/ikinciBahar/ogrenmeDatabase.py", line 231, in kayitEkle
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO biTablo(ad, soyad, numara, puan) VALUES(? ? ? ?)",(ad,soyad,numara,puan))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

what is wrong? what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use python `.format` and change your line from

```
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO biTablo(ad, soyad, numara, puan) VALUES(? ? ? ?)",(ad,soyad,numara,puan))
```

to

```
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO biTablo(ad, soyad, numara, puan) VALUES({},{},{},{})".format(ad,soyad,numara,puan))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `cursor.execute` use `VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to compose the string correctly. Asumming ad,soyad,numara are strings and puan is a number:

> cursor.execute(INSERT INTO biTablo VALUES(\"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\", %f);" % (ad,soyad,numara,puan))

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong this should work:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO biTablo(ad, soyad, numara, puan) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (ad,soyad,numara,puan))
```